# React Query Mutation and TypeScript error - Argument of type '{ surgeryID: any; stageTitle: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm using react-query to fetch, and post data from my database on supabase. I created a hook for adding a record using react-query:

```
export function useCreateSurgeryStage() {
  const { mutate: createSurgeryStage, isLoading: isCreating } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({ surgeryID, stageTitle }) =>
      createSurgeryStageById(surgeryID, stageTitle),
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log(
        // `sent surgery creation request with surgeryID: ${surgeryID} and stageTitle: ${stageTitle}`
        `sent surgery creation request...`
      );
    },
    onError: (err) => console.log("ERROR RECEIVED:", err.message),
  });

  return { isCreating, createSurgeryStage };
}
```

Here's the mutation function that it calls, which is what actually adds the records into the db:

```
interface SurgeryStage {
  surgeryID: number;
  stageTitle: string;
}
export async function createSurgeryStageById(
  surgeryID: number,
  stageTitle: string
): Promise<SurgeryStage> {
  if (!surgeryID || !stageTitle) {
    console.log(
      `createSurgeryStageById API: didn't correctly receive params: surgeryID:${surgeryID}, stageTitle:${stageTitle}`
    );
    return;
  }

  const { data: stage, error } = await supabase.from("Stages").insert([
    {
      surgeryID,
      stageTitle,
    },
  ]);

  if (error) throw error;

  return stage;
}
```

This all works exactly as expected: I can add a record into the database using the hook I made with react-query.
But typescript gives me the warning message:
`Argument of type '{ surgeryID: any; stageTitle: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.`

The warning message is when I try to pass an object into my createSurgeryStage function (which is an alias of the mutate function, from useMutation hook). The handler function:

```
function handleSurgeryStageInsertion({ stageTitle }) {
    const surgeryStage = { surgeryID: channelQuery, stageTitle };
    createSurgeryStage(surgeryStage, {
      onSettled: reset(),
    });
  }
```

Comment: `return;` makes your function potentially return `void`. You need to throw an error instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function is returning a value called `stage`. But in your function declaration you haven't specified what your function will return. If you don't specify the return type then the return type is considered as void by default. If you don't want to return the value `stage` from the function then you can remove the return type or else declare the return type like this:

Some other changes:

1. createSurgeryStageById returns Promise of SurgeryStage or null as you return if values are not given
2. Explicitly return null
3. Define stage for insert as supabase insert does not return `data`
4. Throw new Error
5. Define type of err in `onError: (err: Error)`

```
interface SurgeryStage {
  surgeryID: number;
  stageTitle: string;
}

export async function createSurgeryStageById(
  surgeryID: number,
  stageTitle: string,
): Promise<SurgeryStage | null> { // Added null as return type
  if (!surgeryID || !stageTitle) {
    console.log(
      `createSurgeryStageById API: didn't correctly receive params: surgeryID:${surgeryID}, stageTitle:${stageTitle}`,
    );
    return null; // explicit null as return type
  }

  // declare stage separately
  const stage: SurgeryStage = {
    surgeryID,
    stageTitle,
  };

  const { error } = await supabase.from('Stages').insert([ // the insert query does not return data
    stage
  ]);

  if (error) throw new Error(error.message); // throw the error as new error

  return stage;
}

export function useCreateSurgeryStage() {
  const { mutate: createSurgeryStage, isLoading: isCreating } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({ surgeryID, stageTitle }: SurgeryStage) =>
      createSurgeryStageById(surgeryID, stageTitle),
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log(
        // `sent surgery creation request with surgeryID: ${surgeryID} and stageTitle: ${stageTitle}`
        'sent surgery creation request...',
      );
    },
    onError: (err: Error) => console.log('ERROR RECEIVED:', err.message), // Define type of err
  });

  return { isCreating, createSurgeryStage };
}
```

Also your function is an async function. So we have to wrap SurgeryStage inside Promise.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added your suggested changes to my code. However, I still get that same error.

I should have added in my original post that the warning message I get is from when I try to call the createSurgeryStage function inside a handler function. I updated my original post with that function definition. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: There were multiple type declarations needed. I have updated the answer with the explanation.